# Reset GetAsyncKeyState() to default

Tags: c++, c, virtual-keyboard, getch, kbhit

I am learning to use combination of `kbhit()`, `GetAsyncKeyState()` and `getch()` to build my console game.

I'm using visual studio 2010 express, c/c++ headers are ok for me.

Compability issues(only run at windows platform) does not matter for me.

Take a look at this simple code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<Windows.h>

int main()
{
  printf("Welcome\n");
  while(true)
  {
    if(_kbhit())
    {
      if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_UP))
        printf("UP\n");
      else if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_DOWN))
        printf("DOWN\n");
      else if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LEFT))
        printf("LEFT\n");
      else if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RIGHT))
        printf("RIGHT\n");
      else 
        printf("NOT ARROW\n");
      getch();
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

The problem is: any virtual key input will print **TWICE** while others runs ok.

I don't know what's the problem, but I've found easy fix for it.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<Windows.h>

int main()
{
  printf("Welcome\n");
  while(1)
  {
    if(_kbhit())
    {
      if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_UP))
      {
        printf("UP\n");
        _getch();
      }
      else if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_DOWN))
      {
        printf("DOWN\n");
        _getch();
      }
      else if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LEFT))
      {
        printf("LEFT\n");
        _getch();
      }
      else if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RIGHT))
      {
        printf("RIGHT\n");
        _getch();
      }
      else 
      {
        printf("NOT ARROW\n");
      }
      _getch();
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

My guess is `GetAsyncKeyState()` is not properly cleared to default value

Any explanation?

Also adding `_getch()` for every `kbhit()` and `GetAsyncKeyState()` is kind of redudancy therefore reduce readability, any alternatives?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GetAsyncKeyState "strange" behavior](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35244767/getasynckeystate-strange-behavior)

Answer (score 0):

(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_UP) **& 1**)