# Idenifying pressed HotKey with GetAsyncKeyState() only returns correct result if it's called once before

Tags: c#, winapi, hotkeys

I'm quite confused by this one. I have a method that checks whether or not a HotKey (using [RegisterHotkey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-registerhotkey)) is pressed.
I call [GetAsyncKeyState(vKey)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getasynckeystate) on the hotkey and it's modifiers to determine which of the registered hotkeys is called like so.

```
    public bool IsPressed()
    {
         // Checks if the key and any (but not all) required modifiers are pressed
        // Int16.MinValue indicates that a key is pressed - 0 indicates it isn't - Keys.None cannot be used
        return GetAsyncKeyState(Key) == Int16.MinValue && (Modifier == ModifierKeys.None ||
            (Modifier == ModifierKeys.Shift && GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.ShiftKey) == Int16.MinValue) ||
            (Modifier == ModifierKeys.Alt && GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.Alt) == Int16.MinValue) ||
            (Modifier == ModifierKeys.Control && GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.ControlKey) == Int16.MinValue) ||
            (Modifier == ModifierKeys.Windows && (GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.LWin) == Int16.MinValue || GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.RWin) == Int16.MinValue))
            );
    }
```

The above returns false. So I try to add the statements individually to see where the problem is like so:

```
public bool IsPressed()
{

var keything =  GetAsyncKeyState(Key);

bool a = GetAsyncKeyState(Key) == Int16.MinValue && (Modifier == ModifierKeys.None);
bool b = (Modifier == ModifierKeys.Shift && GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.ShiftKey) == Int16.MinValue);
bool c = (Modifier == ModifierKeys.Alt && GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.Alt) == Int16.MinValue);
bool d = (Modifier == ModifierKeys.Control && GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.ControlKey) == Int16.MinValue);
bool e = (Modifier == ModifierKeys.Windows && (GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.LWin) == Int16.MinValue || GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.RWin) == Int16.MinValue));
bool f = GetAsyncKeyState(Key) == Int16.MinValue && (Modifier == ModifierKeys.None ||
    (Modifier == ModifierKeys.Shift && GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.ShiftKey) == Int16.MinValue) ||
    (Modifier == ModifierKeys.Alt && GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.Alt) == Int16.MinValue) ||
    (Modifier == ModifierKeys.Control && GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.ControlKey) == Int16.MinValue) ||
    (Modifier == ModifierKeys.Windows && (GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.LWin) == Int16.MinValue || GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.RWin) == Int16.MinValue))
    );


// Checks if the key and any (but not all) required modifiers are pressed
// Int16.MinValue indicates that a key is pressed - 0 indicates it isn't - Keys.None cannot be used
return GetAsyncKeyState(Key) == Int16.MinValue && (Modifier == ModifierKeys.None ||
    (Modifier == ModifierKeys.Shift && GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.ShiftKey) == Int16.MinValue) ||
    (Modifier == ModifierKeys.Alt && GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.Alt) == Int16.MinValue) ||
    (Modifier == ModifierKeys.Control && GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.ControlKey) == Int16.MinValue) ||
    (Modifier == ModifierKeys.Windows && (GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.LWin) == Int16.MinValue || GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.RWin) == Int16.MinValue))
    );
}
```

A and F return true - as they should (F is just a copy of the statement being returned as well)...
However, what I did not expect is that the method itself also returns true.

So adding a call to GetAsyncKeyState() before the actual query causes it to work just fine.
Why is this and what's the best way to solve this (aside from a dead call to the function)

Comment: Edited since I know the reason now. I just don't know how the function should be correctly treated.

Comment: I can't run this (virus scanner prevents me), but shouldn't you mask (`state & SomeKey == SomeKey`)? Because [_"if the least significant bit is set, the key was pressed after the previous call to GetAsyncKeyState"_](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getasynckeystate).

Comment: Well.. if my code is picked up by a virus scanner I'm probably taking a horribly wrong approach. :/ Thanks for the tip, I'll try that.

Comment: It's just that ESET detects the presence of the call to `GetAsyncKeyState()` as a keylogger and wipes my executable.

Comment: Maybe I can just add listener for each registered hotkey instead of a single one that tries to determine which hotkey is pressed instead. Probably not the best approach either but i've only got 2-4~ hotkeys total

Comment: Why do that since a hot key posts a specific message to it's window?

Comment: `It's just that ESET detects the presence of the call to GetAsyncKeyState() as a keylogger and wipes my executable.` Great, just what we need (!)

Comment: You're testing the result incorrectly. See [GetAsyncKeyState "strange" behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35244767/getasynckeystate-strange-behavior)

Comment: Thanks, but I found a more obvious approach that doesn't involve calling GetAsyncKeyState at all just now. I didn't know the keypress was passed in lParam.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than the proposed HotKey.IsPressed() using GetAsyncKeyState() - you can instead determine the hotkey from the lParam of the listener like so:

IsPressed in the hotkey class would look like this:

```
public bool IsPressed(IntPtr lParam)
{
    uint param = (uint)lParam.ToInt64();
    var inputKey = (Keys)((param & 0xffff0000) >> 16);
    var inputModifier = (ModifierKeys)(param & 0x0000ffff);

    return inputKey == this.Key && inputModifier == this.Modifier;
}
```

Or use some variant of that where it doesn't have to calculate it on every IsPressed call.